# Cloudsim/Softlayer: gzclient fails to launch on OCU

Tags: cloudsim

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

After running on the local OCU:

. ros.bash

I have shell variables (printenv | grep GAZ)

GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.51:11345

GAZEBO_IP=11.8.0.2

The gzclient launch fails, on a machine that can happily run gazebo locally.

```
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.8.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Open Source Robotics Foundation.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://10.0.0.51:11345
Msg Publicized address: 11.8.0.2
Exception [RenderEngine.cc:579] unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.

Error [Rendering.cc:38] Failed to load the Rendering engine subsystem
unable to find OpenGL rendering system. OGRE is probably installed incorrectly. Double check the OGRE cmake output, and make sure OpenGL is enabled.
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:117] GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI not set
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:117] GAZEBO_MODEL_DATABASE_URI not set
Warning [ModelDatabase.cc:202] Unable to connect to model database using [//database.config]. Only locally installed models will be available.
Error [parser.cc:99] Unable to load file[]
Warning [parser.cc:499] XML Attribute[version] in element[sdf] not defined in SDF, ignoring.
Error [parser.cc:719] XML Element[model], child of element[sdf] not defined in SDF. Ignoring.[]
Warning [parser.cc:427] Unable to parse sdf element[]
Error [parser.cc:337] parse as sdf version 1.4 failed, should try to parse as old deprecated format
Error [SDF.cc:1646] Unable to parse sdf string[0 0 0.0 0 0 01.0 1.0 1.00 0 0.0 0 0 01.0 1.0 1.0file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.materialGazebo/Greytrue]
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Error [WindowManager.cc:96]  Unable to create the rendering window
Exception [WindowManager.cc:103] Unable to create the rendering window
Qt has caught an exception thrown from an event handler. Throwing
exceptions from an event handler is not supported in Qt. You must
reimplement QApplication::notify() and catch all exceptions there.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'gazebo::common::Exception'
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3020/cloudsim/softlayer:-gzclient-fails-to-launch-on-ocu/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Looks like you didn't source the usual `/usr/share/drcsim/setup.sh` on the OCU, which resulted in bad/unset Gazebo/OGRE paths.  I've added that to the [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/CloudSim/VRCUserGuide#Step_2:_Setup_the_private_network_on_the_OCU) and opened [a ticket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/cloudsim/issue/117/add-usr-share-drcsim-setupsh-to-router) to add that line to the generated `router/ros.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0